# Delay in showing the ouput of the .exe file created from a .py file

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have created a .exe file from the .py file using pyinstaller. The issue is everytime I try to run the .exe it takes approximately 24 sec to show the output. In my application as the .exe is called internally this delay is too much. Is there any way for reducing the delay in launching the .exe file ? I know there are a lot of dll dependencies (approximately 19 .dll files) but  still is there any way to reduce the latency ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.   There is no reason, in general, why a frozen python executable should take much time to start up, so something is clearly wrong or unusual with your situation.   Sorry if this isn't much help, but hopefully at least some orientation: the normal experience is that a frozen python executable starts very fast.

Comment: have you tried to disable temporarily a firewall, antivirus software or its analogs on Windows, to test whether the scanning of the executable each time you try to run it is the culprit?

Comment: @ J.F Sebastian thanks for the suggestion. Actually it worked with disabling the firewall (now takes 3 seconds) but the thing is disabling firewall is not a good option for me. Another point i would like to state is even with the firewall enabled if i am running the .exe for the first time it is taking 24 sec but without closing the output window if i am running it again it takes around 3 to 4 sec ... so it looks like first time the delay is caused by the loading of dll files ... even if it's the case i still need to reduce the latency associated with the first run. Is there any way around ?